# ruby use upto with range variable?

Tags: ruby, regex, range

I'm trying to use a variable range with ruby, but my code does not work;

```
ruby  -e   '   input2=145..170 ;  input3=  input2.to_s.gsub(/(.*?)\.\.(.*?)/) {  5.upto($2.to_i) { |i| print i, " " }  }; print input3' > zzmf
```

But I obtained 5170

This part fails:

```
5.upto($2.to_i) { |i| print i, " " }
```

I expected:

```
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 5170
```

Comment: if you are trying to print a range, why not use something like rangeStart = 5; rangeEnd = 170; (rangeStart..rangeEnd).each { |i| print i, " " } ?

Comment: I need extract data from regex expression

Comment: Where is the 5 coming from? Why don't you use 145?

Comment: @alberto2 why do you convert a numeric range (`145..170`) to a string (`"145..170"`) in order to extract the end value (`170`)?

Comment: yes I made various errors

Comment: @alberto2 what are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think gsub is what you need, try the match example below. [2] gets the second match from the regex /(\d+)..(\d+)/ applied to "147..170"

```
5.upto("147..170".match(/(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/)[2].to_i) { |i| print i, " "}
```

gsub is intended for string substitution.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub

Answer (score 0):

I see my code and I confuse in regular expression

I use this .*?

and the correct is this .*

(.*)/

```
    ruby  -e   '   input2=145..170 ;  input3=  input2.to_s.gsub(/(.*?)\.\.(.*)/) {  5.upto($2.to_i) { |i| print i, " " }  }; print input3' > zzmf
```

thanks for your responses